# Multiple insert SQLite : data can't save

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to insert multiple data into sqlite, i get data from server in json format, i parse the data from my activity. and trying to save into my database. But i wonder, how can i save data in sqlite multiple times?
I get some references and and check in my logcat everything is alright. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

```
public List<ModelAgen> updateTaccessUser(){
    List<ModelAgen> data = new ArrayList<ModelAgen>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        String update = "INSERT INTO taccesagen(" +
                "id," +
                "ref_magen," +
                "ref_tuser," +
                "def," +
                "nama" +
                ")" +
                " VALUES" +
                "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            String kondisi;
            if (data.get(i).getDef() == "t") {
                kondisi = "1";
            } else {
                kondisi = "0";
            }
                SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(update);
                insert.bindLong(1, data.get(i).getId());
                insert.bindString(2, data.get(i).getRef_magen());
                insert.bindString(3, data.get(i).getRef_tuser());
                insert.bindString(4, kondisi);
                insert.bindString(5, data.get(i).getNama());
                insert.execute();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert multiple records like this way

```
       try {
                for(int i=0;i<lstModelAgen.size();i++) {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("column1", lstModelAgen.get(i).getcolumn1Value);
                contentValues.put("column2", lstModelAgen.get(i).getcolumn2Value());

                db.insert("taccesagen", null, contentValues);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
           String kondisi;
           if (data.get(i).getDef() == "t") {
                  kondisi = "1";
           } else {
                  kondisi = "0";
           }
           ArrayList<ContentValues> arrvals = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put("id", data.get(i).getId());
           values.put("ref_magen", data.get(i).getRef_magen());
           values.put("ref_tuser",data.get(i).getRef_tuser() );
           values.put("def", kondisi);
           values.put("nama", data.get(i).getNama());
           arrvals.add(values);
          }
          db.InsertData("taccesagen", arrvals);
```